# Remove whitespace padding in matlab fprintf file output

Tags: string, matlab, file-io, formatting, printf

I have large matrices of data that look something like this:

```
DataOut' = [34 1 0.0 -4.75343000000000 0.0291776000000000 5.32835000000000 1.23598000000000 0.890008000000000;
7 1 0.0902364000000000 -4.74065000000000 0.0 1.97133000000000 9.49706000000000 16.1658000000000]
```

The first two columns are IDs and always integers and the remaining 6 columns are 2 pairs of (X,Y,Z) coordinates (Floats) for each respective ID.

I'm writing the data to a file using the following syntax:

```
fprintf(' %u %u %-6.12g %-6.12g %-6.12g %-6.12g %-6.12g %-6.12g \r\n', DataOut)
>>  34 1 0      -4.75343 0.0291776 5.32835 1.23598 0.890008 
    7 1 0.0902364 -4.74065 0      1.97133 9.49706 16.1658
```

This format is fine in almost all cases except the one highlighted above, where the insignificant trailing zeros are replaced with spaces, leading to a big gap between some columns instead of the single space. The software reading this data really doesn't like all theses spaces and breaks when it finds more than the expected one.

My desired output is to only have a single space between each column:

```
>> 34 1 0 -4.75343 0.0291776 5.32835 1.23598 0.890008 
   7 1 0.0902364 -4.74065 0 1.97133 9.49706 16.1658
```

Does anyone know how to get fprintf do just leave one space after removing the insignificant trailing zeros? Using fprintf is nice because I don't need any loops and when you have several thousand of these matrices to be written out I guess that would be quite slow if I had to do some checking in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format spec that you have used for floating point numbers (`%-6.12g`) species that you want to remove trailing zeros that are non-significant (with a maximum of 12 numbers after the decimal). However, the `-6` specifies that you want each field to be *at least* 6 characters wide. In the case of your `0`, it has a width of 1 so `fprintf` will pad it to be 6 characters wide (hence all the whitespace). If you simply remove the `-6` from the beginning of each of your format specifiers you will get the output you desire.

```
fprintf(' %u %u %.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g %.12g \r\n', DataOut)

% 34 7 1 1 0 0.0902364 -4.75343 -4.74065 
% 2.917760e-02 0 5.32835 1.97133 1.23598 9.49706 0.890008 16.1658
```